# how do I create dictionary keys from a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, dictionary

I've been trying to create a script that searches for a pattern in a text file, counts the number of times it occurs and then inserts this as a key-value pair into a dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
fname = raw_input("File name: ")
import re
vars = dict()
lst= list()
count = 0

try:
    fhand = open(fname, "r+")
except:
    print "File not found"
quit()  

for line in fhand:
    line.rstrip()
    if re.search(pattern , line):
        x = re.findall(pattern , line)
        lst.append(x)
    else:
        continue
    for x in lst:
        count += 1
```

What would be the best way to extract text from the regex method and insert it into a dictionary to make it look like this:

```
{'pattern' : count, 'pattern' : count, 'pattern' : count}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple *unique* patterns that you want to store in a dictionary as keys?

Comment: The strings of text I would like to store have the same format but differ in length and characters

Comment: I think you will have to give us some concrete example input text along with the kind of pattern you are trying to count. You can't have the same key in a dictionary more than once, but I suspect that you meant to say that the different 'pattern' in your example are actually different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
fhand = ["<abc> <abc>", "<abc>", "<d>"]

counts = {}
pattern = re.compile(r'<\w+>') # insert your own regex here

for line in fhand:
    for match in pattern.findall(line):
        # initialize the count for this match to 0 if it does not yet exist
        counts.setdefault(match, 0)
        counts[match] += 1
```

Gives

```
counts = {'<abc>': 3, '<d>': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import re

pattern1 = r'([a-z]+)'
pattern2 = r'([0-9])'

regex1 = re.compile(pattern1)
regex2 = re.compile(pattern2)

filename = "somefile.txt"

d = dict()

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        d[pattern1] = d.get(pattern1, 0) + len(regex1.findall(line));
        d[pattern2] = d.get(pattern2, 0) + len(regex2.findall(line));

print d
# output: {'([0-9])': 9, '([a-z]+)': 23}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would use `with` to open your file rather than just `open`.

Ex:

```
with open(fname, "r+") as fhand:
```

Also, I think you're misunderstanding the point of dictionaries. They're key/value stores, meaning, each key is unique. You can't have more than one key.

I think the better solution would be as follows:

```
import collections 

for line in fhand:
line.rstrip()
if re.search(pattern , line):
    x = re.findall(pattern , line)
    lst.append(x)
else:
    continue

counted = collections.Counter(lst)
print counted
```

This will return a dictionary containing the key/value occurrences for your list,